# Measure Windows bootup performance

Tags: windows-7, boot, performance, performance-tuning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Slow startup on Windows 7 Home Premium laptop](https://superuser.com/questions/216207/slow-startup-on-windows-7-home-premium-laptop)

I'm running Windows 7 Home Premium on a 2 GB RAM netbook.

The Windows startup performance, and when coming out of hibernation, seems to be lagging a little more, sometimes due to lack of Wi-Fi, etc.

How can I measure what is taking so long while booting up?

Is there any of the [Sysinternals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winternals) tools that can measure various parts of the Windows boot process, or help me diagnose the tasks and processes that are starting, and how long they are taking?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest and most used application is [Soluto](http://www.soluto.com).

You can also use Windows Performance Tools Kit to analyse your boot performance. This tool give you detailed information about the Windows boot process. To understand the boot phases I recommend you look to for the "[Windows On/Off Transictions](http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/E/7/7E7662CF-CBEA-470B-A97E-CE7CE0D98DC2/OnOffTrans.docx)". In this document, Microsoft provides knowledge base descriptions about all phases and processes that needs to be booted on your system.

I know a good guide to improve your boot-up time, take a look at [here](http://www.briteccomputers.co.uk/forum/tutorials-and-how-to/how-to-speed-up-boot-process-under-windows-vista-or-windows-7).

Comment: Beat me by seconds.

Comment: "Windows On/Off transitions . . ." Interesting. Never heard of this. On technet it's called the boot process.

Comment: Actually On Off Transictions include all transictions: boot, standby, suspend, shutdown.

Comment: I just found the paper you were referring to. . .  Lots of new reading material.

Answer (score 2):

The SU Blog highlighted an app that appears to do a decent job of showing you what is going on and taking time during start up called [Soluto](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/05/12/soluto-review-boot/).

Sysinternals does not have any boot-time tracking tools. Autoruns is brilliant, and Soluto can give you a better understanding of what you see in Autoruns. But Autoruns will not tell you how long each process takes to start.

Comment: -1: Process Monitor *can* log the boot process.

Comment: I was not aware of that. Good to know.

Comment: I believe I have more votes on this one than Diogo has, just most of mine were down. :)

Answer (score 1):

If the already mentioned Soluto doesn't give you the detail you need, [Sysinternals' Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) can also be configured to log the boot process.  Making sense of its output is not for the faint of heart though -- you'll get a *lot* of information.

[Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902) can also offer some insight into what 3rd party software is starting when you boot your PC.  It would be an easier place to start if the problem isn't in a hardware driver.